# Type of memory allocation for a tree in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, tree, stack, dynamic-memory-allocation

I need a function to return a tree built from an expression say AB*B+. Each node is of type `struct`

```
struct Node {
std::string name;
Node* left;
Node* right;
}
```

I need to now parse the expression AB*B+. I have a stack out of `std::vector<Node*>`.

1) Create Node for A, push it on to stack

2) Create Node for B, push it on to stack

3) Create Node for *, pop B, assign it to right, pop A, assign it to left. Push * on to the stack

This goes on until the expression is completed.

Now if I have access to the root of the tree, I should be able to access every node. However, since I allocate all of them on the stack of the function, I am guessing when I return the root Node, though the node may be copied to RHS, the children it points to are invalid.

Should I store all the nodes on a different `std::vector<Node> nodes` the moment it is created. Use the stack to create parent child relationship, then return `nodes` by value? Does this work?

Or should I use `std::shared_ptr` instead for this? If so, can you given an example of how to do it?

Comment: When you say "Create node, push it onto the stack" - do you mean you are allocating a node using new or are you allocating it on the stack? (without new)

Comment: allocate a node without new since I haven't used new until now. But I doubt if that will work.

Comment: I'm not sure how you are getting a vector of Node * without allocating them with new. Unless you are using references. Do you have a code snippet?

Comment: You have to create new nodes with `new`. `shared_ptr` will work. Just replace `Node*` with `std::shared_ptr<Node>` everywhere.

Comment: So the stack will be `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Node>> stack;`
Since I am doing this in a loop, can I just add it to the stack this way, `stack.push_back(new Node())`.

Comment: So you *are* using new! Then you won't have a problem accessing them after returning from the function.

Comment: I guess I have to use new then. But is it okay if I do not store the shared pointer in a variable and directly push it on the vector?

Comment: The benefit of shared pointer is not worrying about pointer ownership. To answer your original question, when you allocate with new - you are allocating on the heap, and as long as you maintain a pointer you can still access the address after you leave scope (in your case - return from the function). But you will have to make sure you delete the nodes when you are done with them to avoid a memory leak. If you don't want to worry about deleting them, go with shared pointers.

Comment: It appears you're making a postfix expression parser. Fair enough. I'd be curious to know what you have for this besides a struct definition. We'd likely have significantly more input on the subject.

Comment: Let me figure out how to describe the rest of information.

Answer (score 0):

By copy, I am guessing you mean this :

```
    Node* root = Null;
    root = nodeStack.pop();
```

I you really are following your algorithm perfectly , and you mean copy as the above. It should work. Definitely. May be there is something wrong with the algorithm implementation.